# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Tags: python, ubuntu, ip, attributeerror, arp

I don't know how I should ask this question. If I make any mistakes, I would appreciate it if someone could correct them.

I am writing a program in python on Ubuntu. In that program I am struggling to get Mac address of remote machine from its IP address (RaspberryPi), connected to network.

But In actual practice, it is giving me an error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Get_MacAddress_from_ip.py", line 9, in <module>
    mac = re.search(r"([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}", s).groups()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`

Can anybody guide me on how do I remove this error? My Coding is given below

```
from Tkinter import *
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

ip = "192.168.2.34"
username = "pi"
remote_MAC="b8:27:eb:d2:84:ef"
pid = Popen(["arp", "-n", ip], stdout=PIPE)
s = pid.communicate()[0]
mac = re.search(r"([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}", s).groups()[0]
mac = re.search(r"(([a-f\d]{1,2}\:){5}[a-f\d]{1,2})", s).groups()[0]
print mac
```

Comment: try printing the string "s" and print the result of the re.search on it (Without the groups() stuff)

Comment: after adding line `print s`, it print `192.168.2.34 (192.168.2.34) -- no entry` what does it means

Comment: Why are you doing two calls to re.search?

Comment: @DanielRoseman from one `re.search`, i didn't get full Mac Address

Comment: But there can't possibly be any point calling it once, assigning the result to a variable, and then immediately overwriting that variable with the result of the second call. This is exactly the same as if you had never done the first call at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman same program is successfully working on other machines on same network

Comment: It might well be, but that doesn't make it any less true that the first call is utterly pointless.

Answer (score 1):

[re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns None if there are no matches. Try assigning the result and checking if it is None:

```
search = re.search(r"([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:|\-]?){6}", s)
mac = None
if search:
    mac = search.groups()[0]
    # You can also do:
    #mac = search.group(0)
print mac
```

Comment: i m only getting  `ef` from full mac address `b8:27:eb:d2:84:ef`